# CommandButton action not worked in insideModalPanel

Tags: jsf, button, command, panel, modal-dialog

h:commandButton action not worked in modalPanel.

I am using t:inputFileUpload component for upload file.   In my richModalPanel have one h:commandButton

**My requirement :**  After browse the file,  and click **upload** commandButton, then i want to show the selected file name in inside ModalPanel.

**My problem is :**
When i click commandbutton in modalPanel, not called commandButton action in bean, and automattically close the modalPanel.

In that action method starting...just i put **System.out.println("Uploading process to be start...");**  Even this output not print in my tomcat log.

```
<body>

<h:form id="UploadForm" binding="#{FileUpload.intiForm}">

  <a4j:outputPanel id="uploadOutputPanel">

    <a4j:commandButton value="ShowModalPanel" 
                       action="#{FileUpload.showUploadPanelAction}"
                       oncomplete="#{rich:component('uploadImagePanel')}.show()"
                       reRender="uploadImagePanel,uploadOutputPanel"/>
  </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>

<rich:modalPanel id="uploadImagePanel" moveable="true" top="150" width="400" autosized="true">

  <h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

      <h:panelGrid id="uploadPanelGridId" columns="2">

            <t:inputFileUpload id="uploadFile"
                               value="#{FileUpload.logoImageFile}"
                               size="54"/>

            <h:commandButton id="UploadButton" 
                             value="Upload"
                             action="#{FileUpload.uploadFileAction}"/>

            <h:outputText value="Uploaded File Name : #{FileUpload.fileName}"/>

       </h:panelGrid>

</h:form> </rich:modalPanel> </body>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>FileUpload</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.jsf.fileupload.FileUpload</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

**FileUpload .java**

```
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm;
import org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile;
public class FileUpload
{

private HtmlForm intiForm;
private String fileName;
private UploadedFile logoImageFile;


public String showUploadPanelAction()
{
    System.out.println("Show Upload Panel Action ....."); //This line showing in tomcat log, when i click "ShowModalPanel" button --> a4j:commandButton
    return "";
}

public String uploadFileAction()
{
    System.out.println("Uploading process to be start....");  //But this line NOT show in my tomcat log, when i click "UploadButton" --> h:commandButton
    System.out.println("logoImageFile : " + logoImageFile);

    if(logoImageFile != null)
    {
        fileName = logoImageFile.getName();
    }

    return "";
}

public HtmlForm getIntiForm(){
    System.out.println("Page initializing......");  //This line showing in tomcat log, when the page loading time
    return intiForm;
}

public void setIntiForm(HtmlForm intiForm) {
    this.intiForm = intiForm;
}

public UploadedFile getLogoImageFile(){
    return logoImageFile;
}

public void setLogoImageFile(UploadedFile logoImageFile){
    this.logoImageFile = logoImageFile;
}

public String getFileName(){
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
```

}

Please help me..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use domElementAttachment="form" to the modal panel

```
<rich:modalPanel id="uploadImagePanel" moveable="true" top="150" width="400"  autosized="true" domElementAttachment="form"> </rich:modalPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for you nice reply...Now i use domElementAttachment. But no use. If i click UploadButton (commandButton)..not call uploadFileAction() method. and also modalPanel is closed when i click that commandButton. Please help me..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do the other prints show up in your log ?

Have you annotated your FileUpload.java with @Named or @ManagedBean ? And its `#{fileUpload.xxx}`, not `#{FileUpload.xxx}`.

And i would also change

```
<h:commandButton id="UploadButton" 
                 value="Upload"
                 action="#{FileUpload.uploadFileAction}"/>
```

with an

```
<a4j:commandButton id="UploadButton"
                   value="Upload"
                   action="#{FileUpload.uploadFileAction}"
                   reRender="uploadImagePanel,uploadOutputPanel">
```

Comment: Thanks @Foumpie for your response. Now i update my post. It means, here i post my faces-config.xml code.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I assumed you were using JEE6 annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if they are related but i'm facing a similar issue when using and h:commandLink inside a form with enctype="multipart/form-data". If I remove this property from the form it works.